# Function to return 3^k in n+1 calls

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Can someone hep me find an algorithm for a recursive function `func(int k)` to return `3^k` in only `n+1` calls where `k` is in the range `[ 3^n, 3^(n+1) )`

For example, the function should return `3^1` or `3^2` in 1 call, `3^3`, `3^4`, `..`, `3^8` in 2 calls, `3^9`, `3^10` .. in 3 calls and so on.

Comment: Umm, wouldn't 3^8 allow 9 calls not 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the algorithm in **untested** C/C++:

```
int 3pow(x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1: return 3;
        case 2: return 9;
        case 3: return 27;
    }

    int remain  = x % 3,
        recur   = 3pow((x-remain)/3),
        combine = recur * recur * recur;

    switch (remain)
    {
        case 0:  return combine;
        case 1:  return combine * 3;
        default: return combine * 9;
    }
}
```

(**I have not compiled, run, or otherwise tested this code. There may be syntax errors and other bugs. But it's sufficient to get the point across.**)

What's different about this algorithm is that it recurses by dividing by 3 instead of 2. This function is rather ugly by necessity, as abstracting away some of the pattern would likely involve more recursion. Still, this algorithm is now O(log<sub>3</sub>n). Here's a table of a given x from 1-50 and the number of recursive calls required (as a two-element lisp list):

```
(1  1) (2  1) (3  1) (4  2) (5  2) (6  2) (7  2) (8  2) (9  2) (10 2)
(11 2) (12 3) (13 3) (14 3) (15 3) (16 3) (17 3) (18 3) (19 3) (20 3)
(21 3) (22 3) (23 3) (24 3) (25 3) (26 3) (27 3) (28 3) (29 3) (30 3)
(31 3) (32 3) (33 3) (34 3) (35 3) (36 4) (37 4) (38 4) (39 4) (40 4)
(41 4) (42 4) (43 4) (44 4) (45 4) (46 4) (47 4) (48 4) (49 4) (50 4)
(51 4) (52 4) (53 4) (54 4) (55 4) (56 4) (57 4) (58 4) (59 4) (60 4)
(61 4) (62 4) (63 4) (64 4) (65 4) (66 4) (67 4) (68 4) (69 4) (70 4)
(71 4) (72 4) (73 4) (74 4) (75 4) (76 4) (77 4) (78 4) (79 4) (80 4)
(81 4) (82 4) (83 4) (84 4) (85 4) (86 4) (87 4) (88 4) (89 4) (90 4)
(91 4) (92 4) (93 4) (94 4) (95 4) (96 4) (97 4) (98 4) (99 4) (100 4)
```

You can see that even as we get up over 100 it only take 4 recursive calls.

Comment: f(2) does not need to be hard coded, it will follow the even rule and get set to f(1) * f(1)

Comment: for f(5), there are three calls, f(5), 3*f(4), f(2)^2. I need that for n=3...8, calls should only be 2.